# Did the Sith play any part in the Yuuzhan Vong war, for either side?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, yuuzhan-vong

I've read the Yuuzhan Vong [Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong) and it makes no mention at all of any Sith until after the war was over.

Did the Sith have absolutely no involvement with the war on either side?

The Yuuzhan Vong hated the Jedi because they were jealous of their affinity with the Force, surely they would have hunted down any Sith for the same reason. I'm assuming that the Yuuzhan Vong would have learned of the existence of the Sith somehow.

Would the Sith have seen the Yuuzhan Vong as a greater threat than the Jedi?

Honestly, I don't even know what Sith, if any, were alive during the war. Maybe there were none.

Comment: Didn't Luke destroy the last of the Sith with Palpatine and Vader?  Or did this occur after Luke restored the Jedi Order?

Comment: Yes, the Yuuzhan Vong war occurred after that. Luke, Han and the guys fight in it. But right after the war, another Sith, Darth Krayt, appears. So maybe there was no Sith during the war after all. I've only read one of the books which make up the EU, no Sith in there, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I've never read any of the EU books, but from what you just described, Krayt sounds like he was the first Sith to emerge after the Empire.  I think that if another Sith had appeared before then, Luke would have done something about it.

Comment: @Robert: Numerous Sith appear between the Battle of Endor and the rise of Darth Krayt, such as Lumiya, Vergere, and Darth Caedus. Luke Skywalker doesn't succeed in foiling all of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they did. Spoiler-alert, obviously.

The Dark Side Force-user and fanatical Imperial, [Brakiss](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Brakiss), started the [Shadow Academy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shadow_Academy) prior to the Yuuzhan Vong War in order to train Force-capable individuals as Sith (though Brakiss himself was more of a wannabe Sith than a true one). While the New Jedi Order shut down the Shadow Academy, killing Brakiss in the process, several of Brakiss's pupils escaped, some eventually linking up with [Darth Krayt's](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Krayt) [One Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/One_Sith).

Two of these Sith trainees, [Welk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Welk) and [Lomi Plo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lomi_Plo), were captured by the Yuuzhan Vong and experimented upon to create the Jedi-hunting [voxyn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Voxyn). A [Jedi strike team](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Myrkr_strike_team) freed these unfortunate Sith when they attacked the voxyn-production facility onboard a [Myrkr-based worldship](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Baanu_Rass). Lomi Plo proved herself very capable of killing Vong with Dark Side techniques, impressing Jaina Solo and Tahiri Veila. The two Sith eventually double-crossed the Jedi strike team, stealing [their ship](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tachyon_Flier), kidnapping [Raynar Thul](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Raynar_Thul) in the process, leading directly to Anakin Solo's death and Jacen Solo's capture. Incidentally, Lomi Plo would be the primary antagonist in the post-Yuuhan Vong War *Dark Nest Crisis*.

Another Sith apprentice, [Vergere](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vergere), betrayed Darth Sidious, her master possibly after discovering he intended to replace her with Anakin Skywalker - decades before the YV War began. Vergere, who was still masquerading as a Jedi Knight whilst training as Sidious's new apprentice - she was Sidious's apprentice after Darth Maul and before Darth Tyrannus - took advantage of a mission to [Zonama Sekot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zonama_Sekot) after a failed attempt to murder Sidious, to flee Republic space. She was still on the living planet when the Yuuhan Vong arrived, atttacking the world. She brokered a cease-fire with the Vong commander, who was horrified to realise he was attacking a liviing, and therefore sacred, planet. Vergere left as a 'hostage' of the Vong, during which she played an unknown role in Shimmra's coup and executor Nom Anorr's infiltration of the galaxy.

Vergere appears to have had little long-term motivation beyond escaping Sidious's wrath, but once the Vong launched a full-scale invasion of the galaxy she initially supported them, but betrayed her patron, the priestess Elan, upon realising that the Jedi Order was led by a Grand Master Skywalker, whom she mistook to be Anakin Skywalker. She disappeared for several months, during which she contacted Darth Vader's former apprentice and self-proclaimed Dark Lady of the Sith, [Lumiya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya), and captured and tortured the future Darth Krayt. Krayt converted to the Sith, but disavowed the Rule of Two, which Lumiya and Vergere both believed in, and so Vergere left to concentrated on someone she and Lumiya agreed would be the perfect convert; Jacen Solo.

To achieve this goal, Vergere returned to the Vong, and tortured the captive Solo. She eventually released him and fled with him, later scrificing her own life to save his, a distinctly un-Sithlike act. This was possibly due to her own advanced age and recognition that Solo was the best chance for the Sith to return to galactic prominence. She was right, as Solo would become the Dark Lord of the Sith, [Darth Caedus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Caedus), after serving as Lumiya's apprentice. Verhere's seduction of Solo was complicated by her need to disguise her actions from first the Vong, and later the Jedi, which might account for the long interval between her preparation of Solo and his eventual fall.

Comment: Excellent answer, cheers James.

Comment: Ok, +1 - it's a better answer than mine, and I'm man enough to admit it.

Comment: Out of curiosity where is the information on the Vergere back story told?  Specifically the 4th paragraph.  I have not read that (though I did get some of the context

Comment: @Chad: Some time during the *Legacy of the Force* series, I think. I haven't actually read it, I just knew it from my previous *Wookieepedia* explorations. Vergere gives a self-serving explanation that covers part of those actions in *Destiny's Way*, leaving out her Sith credentials and focusing instead on trying to convert Luke Skywalker to the Potentium, a heresy created by the Sith to make Jedi more easily corruptible. She is successful, but Skywalker converts back to a more conventional view of the Force later. Jacen Solo does not.

Comment: I have read LOF but I did not see that in there.  Must have missed a book somewhere.

Comment: @Chad: My information is correct, but I may be wrong about the source. As I said, I never actually read the series, merely found the information on *Wookieepedia*. It could have come from a concurrent comic book or something. In fact, some of the story info had accompanying images, so that may very well be it.

Comment: Im am not doubting the veracity of it seems very plausible with what I know.  Actually curious to read the story.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the Sith and Dark Jedi had been wiped out prior to the Yuuzhan Vong invasion. One Dark Jedi - Vergere - lived among the Vong and sided with them during the war. After Vergere's death, the only surviving individual who could lay claim to the title was Lumiya, a former apprentice of Darth Vader. She re-surfaced immediately following the end of the Vong war, calling herself "The Dark Lady of the Sith". She then took as her apprentice

> Jacen Solo, Han & Leia's oldest child. Jacen was turned to the Dark Side and took the name Darth Caedus. The pair found the weakened Galactic Alliance to be easy prey, but were opposed by Han, Leia, Luke, and Jacen's sister Jaina. Eventually Lumiya was killed by Luke Skywalker, and Caedus was later killed by Jaina.

Following the death of these two, the Sith were largely considered extinct. Nearly a hundred years later, however, we discover that another Sith was in hiding all this time.

> A Jedi from the time of the Clone Wars - A'Sharad Hett - emerged as Darth Krayt, the new leader of a Sith army that quickly conquered the Empire.

Essentially, it appears that the Sith will always exist in some form or other. Even when they seem to be gone, there is always someone willing to take up the banner of the Sith and begin anew.

Comment: The very final Sith is defeated and the galaxy is safe! ...no wait, there's another one (and repeat). :D

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there were no Sith active during the YV war...unless you've read the post-YV war books (which I haven't).

Wookieepedia claims that [Lumiya](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya) and [Vergere](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vergere) were both Sith, but they were never called out as such in any of the YV books.  Their existence as users of the Dark Side was known (or at least suspected, as Vergere in particular claimed there was no Dark Side) but they weren't said to be *Sith*.  It was only in later books, as Jacen Solo became Darth Caedus, that their Sith roots were 'revealed'.

Both Lumiya and Vergere played significant parts in the YV war, but those parts were mainly in support of other characters.  Lumiya worked in the shadows against them, and Vergere mainly spent her time torturing and/or teaching Jacen.

Essentially, it looks to me as if the Sith were considered gone prior to and during the YV war (from the writer's perspective, at least) and later back-filled in when it was decided that they would be appropriate villains in later books.